# How to mark a region so clang-format won't touch it?

Tags: c++, clang-format

For example, in the MySQL++ library there are macros that can be used to define simple structs based on sql table definition, like this:

```
sql_create_6(stock, 1, 6,
    mysqlpp::sql_char, item,
    mysqlpp::sql_bigint, num,
    mysqlpp::sql_double, weight,
    mysqlpp::sql_decimal, price,
    mysqlpp::sql_date, sdate,
    mysqlpp::Null<mysqlpp::sql_mediumtext>, description)
```

The problem is that clang-format will reformat this in a way that is much more difficult to read (every param on a new line).
Most code formatters can recognize special format-off / format-on comments, but I haven't found anything like that in the clang-format manual.

Answer (score 170, accepted):

In newer version, you can surround a section of code with:

```
// clang-format off
...
// clang-format on
```

Comment: I see this in [the documentation](http://releases.llvm.org/3.6.0/tools/clang/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html) as early as 3.6, but it didn't work for me initially although I am on 3.8.  I had not replicated whitespace identically - make sure to get the spaces!

Comment: Now I just wish I knew a way to disable it from for entire codebase downward in the .clang-format file, because people using VS 2017+ blindly trounce on my codebase because they have it enabled in the UI, then submit PR's with lots of noise.  The issue is that higher directories from other projects can include a .clang-format file above our code included as a submodule. [update] Ah, found it: `DisableFormat: true`

Comment: Sadly, I've found the // clang-format off trick to not always work, but it does 99% of the time, so the best approach I know. Sometimes, I find I have to move the troubling code to the end of the file to prevent clang from being confused and mis-formatting the rest. Use of #if a, along with code with [[deprecated()]] seems to really confuse clang-format sometimes, so even // clang-format off won't make it happy.

Comment: Note that it seems that you need to write the comment _exactly_ like that; just adding/removing spaces in this comment causes it to be ignored. Tested with clang-format 15.0.3.

Answer (score 9):

Try adding a `//` comment marker after each line, this may do it. I had the same issue in Eclipse and learned this trick.

```
sql_create_6(stock, 1, 6, //
    mysqlpp::sql_char, item, //
    mysqlpp::sql_bigint, num, //
    mysqlpp::sql_double, weight, //
    mysqlpp::sql_decimal, price, //
    mysqlpp::sql_date, sdate, //
    mysqlpp::Null<mysqlpp::sql_mediumtext>, description)
```

Comment: This didn't worked. But the `// clang-format on/off` did. I am editing in Eclipse and running via command line the `clang-format` tool.

Answer (score 5):

I noticed that

`//clang-format off` didn't work but
`// clang-format off` did!

The space after `//` made all the difference.