# How to make clang-format skip sections of c++ code

Tags: c++, qt, clang-format

Is there any way to configure the `clang-format` tool to skip my `Qt::connect` function calls ? There are several connects in my constructors which looks like these:

```
connect( m_Job, SIGNAL( error( const QString&, const QString& ) ),  this, SLOT( onError( const QString&, const QString& ) ) );
connect( m_Job, SIGNAL( message( const QString& ) ),                this, SLOT( onMessage( const QString& ) ) );
connect( m_Job, SIGNAL( progress( int, int ) ),                     this, SLOT( onProgress( int, int ) ) );
```

but after I run the formatting tool it makes it less readable:

```
connect( m_Job, SIGNAL( error(const QString&, const QString&)), this, SLOT( onError(const QString&, const QString&)) );
connect( m_Job, SIGNAL( message(const QString&)), this, SLOT( onMessage(const QString&)) );
connect( m_Job, SIGNAL( progress(int, int)), this, SLOT( onProgress(int, int)) );
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to mark a region so clang-format won't touch it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24974919/how-to-mark-a-region-so-clang-format-wont-touch-it)

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Use `// clang-format off` and `// clang-format on` to make it skip code sections.

```
// clang-format off
// Don't touch this!
connect( m_Job, SIGNAL( error( const QString&, const QString& ) ),  this, SLOT( onError( const QString&, const QString& ) ) );
connect( m_Job, SIGNAL( message( const QString& ) ),                this, SLOT( onMessage( const QString& ) ) );
connect( m_Job, SIGNAL( progress( int, int ) ),                     this, SLOT( onProgress( int, int ) ) );
// clang-format on
// Carry on formatting
```

Comment: How should I do this ? Please write some details.

Comment: @p.i.g. Quite literally just add these comments around your code to have clang-format ignore it. Just copy-paste the code in this answer if you can't wrap your mind around it for the moment. It'll be clear once you do :)

Answer (score 1):

As an aside: You should be normalizing the signal/slot signatures. Thus, the references and const-references are not needed, the signature normalization code within Qt simply removes them. You also don't need the third parameter if it's `this`.

Your code should look as follows:

```
connect(m_Job, SIGNAL(error(QString,QString)), SLOT(onError(QString,QString)));
connect(m_Job, SIGNAL(message(QString)), SLOT(onMessage(QString)));
connect(m_Job, SIGNAL(progress(int,int)), SLOT(onProgress(int,int)));
```

If you insist, there certainly can be spaces between the parameter types, at some runtime cost of course since the normalization code isn't a no-op anymore.

You can also leverage `QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName` to get rid of explicit connections. This requires that `m_Job` is a child of `this`, and has a name. For example:

```
class Foo : public Q_OBJECT {
  Job m_job;
  Q_SLOT void on_job_error(const QString&, const QString&);
  Q_SLOT void on_job_message(const QString&);
  Q_SLOT void on_job_progress(int, int);
public:
  Foo(QObject * parent = 0) :
    QObject(parent),
    m_job(this)
  {
    m_job.setObjectName("job");
    QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName(this);
  }
};
```

The slots with names having the pattern `on_name_signal` will be automatically connected by `connectSlotsByName`. The `name` is the name of the sender object, and `signal` is the name of the signal.

Finally, the excessive whitespace can make your code harder, not easier, to read. This is not an issue of style, but of simple physiology. [Fovea centralis](http://www.wikiwand.com/en/Fovea_centralis) is about 2 angular degrees in diameter. One angular degree of vision is about the width of your thumb at arms' length. Reading code with excessive whitespace requires more saccades/fixations to relocate your central vision along the line of code. Figure 0.15-0.2s needed to process each fixation's worth of data and integrate it with your mental model of the code you're reading. It's all measurable.

As an anecdote, not medical advice: I can't read dense sheet music without +0.5 glasses on my nose. My vision is otherwise completely normal. YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [new signal slot syntax](https://wiki.qt.io/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax) for better readable. Its look much simplier

`connect(sender, &Sender::valueChanged, receiver, &Receiver::updateValue);`

Comment: Another benefit of this syntax, your compiler will complain of non-existant/incompatible syntax/slot whereas the old syntax produces a runtime error

Comment: Okay, I know but it would be nice to use a table-like layout for this purpose like in my first example. A table with headers: sender, signal, receiver, slot. If I have a lot of connections and I don't use this format it makes it difficult to read. I use Qt5.