# Is it possible to create custom rules for clang-format?

Tags: c++, qt, coding-style, clang-format

There a some external libraries that use a unique coding style.
One example would be Qt's signal/slot-connect syntax.

```
connect(sender.data(), &Sender::valueChanged,
        receiver,      &Receiver::updateValue);
```

clang-format using a slightly modified llvm formatting reorders this statement to

```
connect(sender.dataa(), &Sender::valueChanged, receiver, &Receiver::updateValue);
```

or

```
connect(sender.dataa(),
        &Sender::valueChanged,
        receiver,
        &Receiver::updateValue);
```

if it exceeds the 80-character limit.

Is there a possibility to create custom rules for special commands like this, so that it gets formatted as in the first example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know of a way to create custom rules, but a workaround could be to tell clang-format to skip the relevant sections with `// clang-format off` and `// clang-format on`.
(See [How to make clang-format skip sections of c++ code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33258159/how-to-make-clang-format-skip-sections-of-c-code#33258592))