# Clang-Format breaks indents with a function header in ifdefs

Tags: c, clang-format

I am currently writing a cross-platform bit of networking code. I use pthread on Unix (#ifdef __unix__) and winsock2 on Windows (#ifdef _WIN32). I have a function that requires a different return value based on the library being used. This ends up with a bit of code that looks as follows:

```c
#ifdef __unix__
void *msgThread(void *arg) {
#endif
#ifdef _WIN32
DWORD WINAPI msgThread(void *arg) {
#endif
    //code stuff here
}
```

However, Clang-Format (using Google's style) is misinterpreting the braces as both existing and is indenting the code like this:

```c
#ifdef __unix__
void *msgThread(void *arg) {
#endif
#ifdef _WIN32
    DWORD WINAPI msgThread(void *arg) {
#endif
        //code stuff here
    }
```

I understand that I can put the open brace on a new line outside of the #ifdefs, however this does not follow the style we are currently using for the project. Is there any setting in Clang-Format that fixes this issue?

Comment: You can disable clang-format specifically for those lines - this answers explains how https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24974919/how-to-mark-a-region-so-clang-format-wont-touch-it

Comment: Zenith2198, I hope the true code well handles (or _meaningfully_ errors) if neither `__unix__`, `_WIN32` are defined.